# How to Pass User Roles to View as ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

An admin should be able to create a user and select which role the user belongs to.

My `CreateUserViewModel` looks like:

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My controller action looks like:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var model = new CreateUserViewModel();
    ApplicationDbContext appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    // this is the part that doesn't work because of the following error:
    // Error 1
    // Cannot implicitly convert type
    // 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>'
    // to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AspNetMvcProject.Models.ApplicationRole>'.
    // An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    model.Roles = appDbContext.Roles;
    return View();
}
```

The main purpose of this is to be able to get the **`list of roles`** available so that the admin creating the user can select which roles the user should belong in a `<select>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the list of roles from your Entity Framework DBSet (`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole`) into `blb_pgin_bprp.Models.ApplicationRole` instances.

One way you could this is like so:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
   var model = new CreateUserViewModel();
   ApplicationDbContext appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

   model.Roles = appDbContext.Roles.Select(r => new lb_pgin_bprp.Models.ApplicationRole { Id = r.ID, Name = r.Name }).ToList();
   return View();
}
```

You use `Select` on the database roles to create instances of your ApplicationRole, picking out the `ID` and `Name`

EDIT:

You may need to do something like:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
   var model = new CreateUserViewModel();
   ApplicationDbContext appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

   var rolesFromDb = appDbContext.Roles.ToList();

   model.Roles = rolesFromDb.Select(r => new lb_pgin_bprp.Models.ApplicationRole { Id = r.ID, Name = r.Name }).ToList();

   return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. But this line: model.Roles = appDbContext.Roles.Select(r => new AspNetMvcProject.Models.ApplicationRole { Id = r.ID, Name = r.Name }).ToList(); returns "cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"